# XML parse for special characters containing in Element

Tags: xml-validation

I want to read the below XML using XMLREADER.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

    <Inforamtion>
        <Name;Property>Name contain
        </Name;Property>
        <123>89</123>
        <question?>
        </question?>
    </Inforamtion>
```

But it throws me error for special character containing in element name.
and element name's first char can't be a number.

I can have any such xml in bulk to process and correct it.

Please guide me how to process such XML or correct it  or read it?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is not valid. 
This document :
[What are the rules for a valid XML element name?](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html) will help you correct this XML.

A summary :

> A Name is a token beginning with a letter or one of a few punctuation
>   characters ( [_] and [:]) , and continuing with letters, digits, hyphens, underscores,
>   colons, or full stops, together known as name characters.

Comment: I know XML is invalid but, I want such parser or methods to correct such file and then i can proceed with XMLREADER to read it or load the xml document.     Please provide any code or algorithm for the parser.